# Differences between local app and deployed into Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, materialize

I have the following problem, I'm developing an app on Rails using materialize CSS instead of Bootstrap; the fact is when I need to charge some JavaScript to see, for example, "dropdown menu" or a "select", in local version it works OK but when I deploy to Heroku, I need reload the page just to see this elements.
I've seen in Chrome inspector both apps, and something strange I found in "source":

Local version

```
<head>
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/jquery.easing.1.3.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/velocity.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/hammer.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/jquery.hammer.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/collapsible.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/dropdown.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/leanModal.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/materialbox.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/parallax.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/tabs.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/waves.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/toasts.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/sideNav.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/scrollFire.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/scrollspy.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/forms.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/slider.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/cards.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/pushpin.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/animations.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/buttons.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/transitions.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/date_picker/picker.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize/date_picker/picker.date.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize-sprockets.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/owl.carousel.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/index.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.mmenu.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materialize.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/script.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/section.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/shopping_cart.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="cmwx+6SEw1CKtoScvCUqgEP77I8PGySQvztPPo3MKgw=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
```

Heroku version

```
<head>
  <link href="/assets/application-b804f5fbe6a002a548de7e30161c225b.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="/assets/application-9fe0c4c49ba13eb54f93880ba7ad932e.js"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="j+oWzNXf5+jUhodRLG7+4vPKp9ybgieDaFCZfJCMAXo=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
```

I puts some files of my project

```
#application.js 
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require materialize-sprockets
//= require owl.carousel
//= require_tree .
```

I call the function here

```
 <script>$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
  });</script>
  <body>
<h3 class="center-align teal-text thin"> Publica un nuevo producto </h3> 
<%= render 'form' %>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep your production assets exactly like development, compare `config/environments/development.rb` and `config/environments/production.rb`. Set the asset config lines in development equal to the asset config lines in production.

A better option would be maintaining the minification for performance reasons. I would recommend looking into source maps to debug in production. You can find a good introduction to using source maps here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-using-cross-browser-source-maps--cms-24430

Comment: Great! i copy/paste what i have on config/environments/development.rb to config/environments/production.rb and it works !